# Install Sequence

Tags: wix, wix3

I am writing an installer which has a EULA, and then a dialog to ask whether they want to do a 'custom install', or 'default install'.

If they select custom they get a bunch of dialogs relating to SQL settings (as shown below with the next button starting the 'StartupMenu' dialog if they have selected custom install).

If they select default the installer should skip to the 'installing' stage and not ask any more questions. How do I do this?

My next button is defined like this,

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="no" Text="Next" >
  <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="StartupMenu" >CUSTOMINSTALL = 1</Publish>
  <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return">CUSTOMINSTALL = 0</Publish>
</Control>
```

When CUSTOMINSTALL = 1 it is fine, but it is the next line, what do I have to put with CUSTOMINSTALL = 0 to make it go straight to the installation stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an update on this one. I found that the first issue was with my InstallUISequence table, I had to make it like this,

```
<InstallUISequence>
    <Custom Action="CreateConnectionStrings" After="ExecuteAction">NOT Installed</Custom>
    <Show Dialog="CustomInstall" After="WelcomeEulaDlg" >NOT Installed</Show>
    <Show Dialog="StartupMenu" After="CustomInstall" >NOT Installed and CUSTOMINSTALL = 1</Show>
    <Show Dialog="iCalibraDatabaseSelection" After="StartupMenu">NOT Installed and CUSTOMINSTALL = 1</Show>
    <Show Dialog="GlobalStoreDatabaseSelection" After="iCalibraDatabaseSelection">NOT Installed and CUSTOMINSTALL = 1</Show>
</InstallUISequence>
```

Note that on StartupMenu, iCalibraDatabaseSelection, and GlobalStoreDatabaseSelection dialogs I have added the new condition CUSTOMINSTALL = 1.

This solves my problem when I select the 'default install' option. This skips to the installation process.

The problem I have now is when I select the 'custom install' option. I go through each of the above dialogs and the GlobalStoreDatabaseSelection dialog should be the last dialog. On that dialog I have this,

```
<Control Id="Install" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Disabled="no" Text="Install" >
      <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="Return"></Publish>
</Control>
```

But this does not progress the installer to do the actual installation. It jumps back to the StartupMenu dialog.

So I guess what does Event="EndDialog" Value="Return" actually do? Where does it jump to?